# PyGame is Choppy

Tags: python, macos, animation, pygame

im new at pygame and im watching some tutorials in how to get started with it, I wrote this basic code that it only has movement and a jump "function" but it is really choppy, I do not think its my hardware (Macbook Pro 2018). Do someone has any idea of whats happening?

Here´s the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win_width = 500
win_height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width,win_height))

    pygame.display.set_caption("First PyGame")

    width = 40
    height = 60
    x = win_width/2
    y = win_height/2
    vel = 10

    isJump = False
    jumpCount = 10

    run = True
    while run:
        pygame.time.delay(100)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("adios putito")
                run = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
            x -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < win_width - width - vel:
            x+= vel
        if not (isJump):
            if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
                y -= vel
            if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]and y < win_height - height - vel:
                y += vel
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                isJump = True
        else:
            if jumpCount >= -10:
                neg = 1
                if jumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -1
                y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
                jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                isJump = False
                jumpCount = 10

        win.fill((0,0,0))
        pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,255,255), (x,y,width,height))
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I don't know much about pygame but at first glance `pygame.time.delay(100)` looks suspicious.

Comment: in the video just says that its like the "game clock" but i dont know why, but my code is exactly as the tutorial guy, but mine is choppy :/

Comment: @Phix you were right, i just removed that line and everything is just working fine! Thks!

Comment: @AbrahamEsquivel What tutorial is it? That's not how you use a game clock. You should create a clock with `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` at the start of your program, and then use `clock.tick(60)` at the place you have `pygame.time.delay(100)`.

Comment: Make sure to mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
pygame.time.delay(100)
```

is delaying your script that milliseconds, remove that line and it should work just fine!

Result:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win_width = 500
win_height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width,win_height))

    pygame.display.set_caption("First PyGame")

    width = 40
    height = 60
    x = win_width/2
    y = win_height/2
    vel = 10

    isJump = False
    jumpCount = 10

    run = True
    while run:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("adios putito")
                run = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
            x -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < win_width - width - vel:
            x+= vel
        if not (isJump):
            if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
                y -= vel
            if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]and y < win_height - height - vel:
                y += vel
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                isJump = True
        else:
            if jumpCount >= -10:
                neg = 1
                if jumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -1
                y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
                jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                isJump = False
                jumpCount = 10

        win.fill((0,0,0))
        pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,255,255), (x,y,width,height))
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's still a good idea to have a game clock that delays your program enough to keep a persistent framerate. You can use pygame's `pygame.time.Clock` object and use its `tick()` method to delay your game. The `tick` method takes an integer which represents the FPS you want your game to cap at. If your game runs slower than the FPS value you put in, no delay will happen.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win_width = 500
win_height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width,win_height))

    pygame.display.set_caption("First PyGame")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    width = 40
    height = 60
    x = win_width/2
    y = win_height/2
    vel = 10

    isJump = False
    jumpCount = 10

    run = True
    while run:
        # Delay your game to try and keep 60 FPS.
        clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("adios putito")
                run = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
            x -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < win_width - width - vel:
            x+= vel
        if not (isJump):
            if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
                y -= vel
            if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]and y < win_height - height - vel:
                y += vel
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                isJump = True
        else:
            if jumpCount >= -10:
                neg = 1
                if jumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -1
                y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
                jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                isJump = False
                jumpCount = 10

        win.fill((0,0,0))
        pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,255,255), (x,y,width,height))
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
```